# Google OAuth problem with project's Icon URL?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play, google-play-services

We're trying to get our game authorized and we got a feedback that "there's a problem with your project's Icon URL." I can't find what it could possibly mean in Google's policy. It's the same icon we use for Google Play listing in jpg format, we didn't send any URL as you upload icon from Google's built in interface. Anyone had similar issue while getting a review?

Comment: I'm having the same response for an icon update too. Their review process seems engineered to discourage people.

Comment: We managed to fix it by adding game icon somwhere on our homepage.

Comment: For my Addon, the icon of the listing on the google workspace marketplace hadn't been updated and was different form the one shown on the authorization screen